# Negative time in recent activities

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, recent-activity

I managed to see a future vote before it happened, or there is some bug with the time display in the recent activities. This happened on area51, but it's probably generic to all SE sites.

**Image:**
[image http://grab.by/grabs/ee4926a2dadc02bdc2e59fd3dda7a715.png](http://grab.by/grabs/ee4926a2dadc02bdc2e59fd3dda7a715.png)

Comment: that's perfectly legit when you travel faster than light

Comment: Also, look at the proposal this belongs on: [Conspiracy Theories](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4659/conspiracy-theories-and-conspiracy-theorists). Any more proves needed? :p

Comment: @Tobias I just knew that Joel and Jeff were in on it.

Comment: We have been playing with flux capacitors ... should be fixed at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a result of the clocks being slightly off on the different servers.  I've fixed it so we never show a negative number, and let the sysadmins know they should get their act together :)

Comment: It has happened again just now.